# Animate rotation of SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am attempting to rotate an `SKSpriteNode` to face the direction of a `CGPoint`. I have managed to do this like so:

```
CGPoint direction = rwNormalize(offset);

self.player.zRotation = atan2f(direction.y, direction.x);
```

How would I call this so that the `SKSpriteNode` will animate its rotation rather than it being instantaneous. Would it also be possible to keep the **same speed** of rotation in the animation no matter where the sprite should turn? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SKAction`:

```
CGPoint direction = rwNormalize(offset);
float angle = atan2f(direction.y, direction.x);
// Speed of rotation (radians per second)
float speed = 2.0;

float duration = angle > M_PI_2 ? angle/speed : (angle + M_PI_2)/speed;
[self.player runAction:
    [SKAction rotateToAngle:angle duration:duration]];
```