# Rotate sprite with path

Tags: sprite-kit, bezier, 2d-games

Hi i have a sprite following a path that is a bezier curve and id like the sprite to rotate to the direction it is currently moving, i can tell it to follow the path by setting `orientToPath` to `YES` in

```
SKaction *enemyCurve = [SKAction followpath:cgpath asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:5];
```

but this just results in the sprite facing the final point of movement. Any suggestions on how i can make it rotate to the current direction its traveling in?
I have included the code i use for the path below. Thank you for any help and suggestions.

```
-(void)AddEnemy:(MotionType *)motion :(CGPoint*)Start :(CGPoint*)Finish :(EnemyType)enemyType{
double curTime = CACurrentMediaTime();

if (enemyType == One) {
    if(curTime > _nextAsteroidspawn)
    {
        float randSecs = [self randomValueBetween:0.20 andValue:1.0];
        _nextAsteroidspawn = randSecs + curTime;

        float randY = [self randomValueBetween:0.0 andValue:self.frame.size.height];
        float randDuration = [self randomValueBetween:2.0 andValue:10.0];


        SKSpriteNode *asteroid = [_Asteroids objectAtIndex:_nextAsteroid];
        _nextAsteroid++;

        if(_nextAsteroid >= _Asteroids.count){
            _nextAsteroid = 0;
        }



        [asteroid removeAllActions];
        asteroid.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+asteroid.size.width/2, 50);
        asteroid.hidden = NO;

        CGMutablePathRef cgpath = CGPathCreateMutable();

        CGPoint startingPoint = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width+asteroid.size.width/2 , 50);

        CGPoint controlPoint1 = CGPointMake(160, 300);
        CGPoint controlPoint2 = CGPointMake(200, 600);

        CGPoint endingPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.width - self.frame.size.width - asteroid.size.width / 2);

        CGPathMoveToPoint(cgpath, NULL, startingPoint.x, startingPoint.y);
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(cgpath, NULL, controlPoint1.x, controlPoint1.y, controlPoint2.x
                              , controlPoint2.y, endingPoint.x
                              , endingPoint.y);


        SKAction *enemyCurve = [SKAction followPath:cgpath asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:5];



        CGPoint location = CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width-asteroid.size.width, randY);

        SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:location duration:randDuration];
        SKAction *doneAction = [SKAction runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)^(){

            asteroid.hidden = YES;
        }];


        SKAction *moveAsteroidActionWithDone = [SKAction sequence:@[enemyCurve,moveAction, doneAction]];

        [asteroid runAction:moveAsteroidActionWithDone withKey:@"asteroidMoving"];

        CGPathRelease(cgpath);

        //[asteroid runAction: [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:_Asteroids timePerFrame:0.1f]]];
    }
```

The code that creates the enemy node can be seen bellow, i do not apply any rotations to the node.

In initWithSize:

```
_Asteroids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:knumAsteroids];
        for(int i = 0; i < knumAsteroids; i++)
        {
            SKSpriteNode *asteroid = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"enemyBasic1"];
            asteroid.hidden = YES;
            [_Asteroids addObject:asteroid];
            [self addChild:asteroid];
        }
```

In Update:

```
[self AddEnemy:BezierCurve :NULL :NULL:One];
```

The method in update just links to the code posted at the top which determines the path the enemy will take i have also updated it to include the entire method.

Comment: Make the node face towards a specific CGPoint. This link explains how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423622/animate-rotation-of-skspritenode

Comment: the sprite i am using rotate automatically with the same code. are you doing something else to the enemy node?

Comment: I suggest you post the code that creates the enemy node.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, i've updated it to include the code that creates the enemy and the full method where the path is created and applied.

Comment: You will need to calculate the angle of rotation, and update the sprite's zRotation in the physics update methods, At least that's what I do.